# Oracle APEX Shuttle Item - display 2nd shuttle item based on 1st shuttle item values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Apex Page to create meeting appointments. There are 2 items in it

1. Participating Departments
2. Participating Employees

The employees who would be participating should be only from the selected "participating departments".

Both are shuttle items. In the first one I am displaying

```
SELECT DEPTNAME, DEPTNO FROM DEPARTMENTS
```

For the second one, I should be using

```
SELECT EMPNAME, EMPNO FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPTNO IN (<<the selected departments>>)
```

Now I am having difficulty to form these selected departments in query. Can someone help on this?

MY SECOND QUESTION:
I need to also display the appointments as an interactive report. Since I am saving all the selected departments as numerical values (for ex 2:3:7), the report is displaying these deptno, instead of departmentname (For ex, HR,Finance,Reception)

Can someone help me with 2nd question pls?

Comment: Only ask one question at a time. It doesn't cost anything to create another question.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp In this case questions are close to each other (I would like to say - in fact, it is a one question), I think it is not a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
select regexp_substr('1:2:3','[^:]+', 1, level) ID from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1:2:3', '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
```

splits your string to table

```
ID
--
 1
 2
 3
```

After that you can use this query as subquery in `WHERE DEPTNO IN (...)` clause and join it with LOV source for Interactive Report.